# Group repeated regex?

Tags: regex

I would like to match the following text:

```
PokerStars Hand #95528134282: Tournament #2013004001, $0.10+$0.01 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level VI (100/200) - 2013/03/14 15:35:36 WET [2013/03/14 11:35:36 ET]
Table '2013004001 5898' 9-max Seat #1 is the button
Seat 1: Pucharrin (7250 in chips) 
Seat 2: pahol (24180 in chips) 
Seat 3: dno16 (2000 in chips) 
Seat 4: sogd20i07 (150 in chips) is sitting out
Seat 5: koaollie (13680 in chips) 
Seat 6: vovik770 (6307 in chips) 
Seat 7: gab341978 (6920 in chips) 
Seat 8: 19gow63 (1000 in chips) 
Seat 9: pokerplayer (9048 in chips) 
pahol: posts small blind 100
dno16: posts big blind 200
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to pokerplayer [3s 9d]
sogd20i07: folds 
koaollie: folds 
vovik770: folds 
gab341978: folds 
19gow63: raises 800 to 1000 and is all-in
pokerplayer: folds 
Pucharrin: folds 
pahol: raises 1000 to 2000
dno16: calls 1800 and is all-in
*** FLOP *** [4s 7c Ah]
*** TURN *** [4s 7c Ah] [Qs]
*** RIVER *** [4s 7c Ah Qs] [Ks]
*** SHOW DOWN ***
pahol: shows [Qc Qd] (three of a kind, Queens)
dno16: shows [6h 2h] (high card Ace)
pahol collected 2000 from side pot
19gow63: shows [Kd 2s] (a pair of Kings)
pahol collected 3000 from main pot
19gow63 re-buys and receives 1000 chips for $0.10
dno16 re-buys and receives 2000 chips for $0.20
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 5000 Main pot 3000. Side pot 2000. | Rake 0 
Board [4s 7c Ah Qs Ks]
Seat 1: Pucharrin (button) folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 2: pahol (small blind) showed [Qc Qd] and won (5000) with three of a kind, Queens
Seat 3: dno16 (big blind) showed [6h 2h] and lost with high card Ace
Seat 4: sogd20i07 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 5: koaollie folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 6: vovik770 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 7: gab341978 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
Seat 8: 19gow63 showed [Kd 2s] and lost with a pair of Kings
Seat 9: pokerplayer folded before Flop (didn't bet)
```

And I would like to capture the lines starting with "Seat somenumber: someplayername (somenumber in chips) someoptionaltext" as a group.
I tried the following regex:

```
PokerStars.*?Level .+? \(\d+\/(\d+)\) (?:.|\s)*?((?:Seat \d+: .*? \(\d+ in chips\)(?:.|\s)*?)+)(?:.|\s)*?(.*?) collected (\d+)
```

but it only captures the first occurence "Seat 1: Pucharrin (7250 in chips) ".

How can I change it to capture the group?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried tried `preg_match_all`?

Comment: Which language? E.g., JavaScript, Perl, ...?

Comment: What technology are you using?

Comment: I am testing the regex here http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/. I am using autohotkey which has PCRE compatible regex. I am using preg_match_all.

Comment: Can't `Seat \d: \w+` suit your needs?

Comment: Why are you matching against `PokerStars.*?Level .+?` if you want "*lines starting with "Seat…*"?

Comment: Because I am matching from a file that contains several instances of the text in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regexp that captures the data you need. When you specify the syntax/ordering of those elements, I could revamp it for you

`(Seat\s(\d)+:\s+([\w\d\-\_\.]+)\s+\((\d+)\s+in\s+chips\)(.*))`

I used your service and input to test it, seems to work fine.

-- EDIT --

Unless you want the entire block starting with `PokerStars` and stopping at the last `)`
Then maybe:

```
if (preg_match('/((?:PokerStars.*\s*Table.*[\r\n]*)(?:Seat.*\s+)+)/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: But I also want to match the beginning thats stars with "Pokerstars". If I change your regex to this Pokerstars(?:.|\s)*?(Seat\s(\d)+:\s+([\w\d\-\_\.]+)\s+\((\d+)\s+in\s+chips\)(.*))  it won't match.

Comment: Please provide a plaintext results of what you want to accomplish. That way I can try to finetune the regexp